# Ionic Angular Content with Images only and turn into Slider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm grabbing data from WordPress, which only has images in its content. It is showing all of the images but how do I make it into a slider instead?

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div *ngIf="selectedItem" class="selection">

    <h2 [innerHTML]="selectedItem.title.rendered"></h2>

    <div *ngIf="content" [innerHTML]="content"></div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

The content has all of the images. I'm thinking of the ion-slides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use ion-slides i have implemented this inside one of my apps.
try this code.

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-slides *ngIf="content">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of content">
        <ion-card no-padding>
          <img [src]="item.imageName"> // use your image property instead imageName or if you directly receive image in item use item
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```